# gloabal scroll to top is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a scroll to the top button globally in my application but the problem is on one page it's working fine but on the other page, it's not even working. I have no idea why.

This is how my code looks

> App.js

```
const AuthenticationRoute = (props) => {
  const [showScroll, setShowScroll] = useState(false);

  const checkScrollTop = (event) => {
    console.log('checkScrollTop', window);
    if (!showScroll && window.scrollbars.visible && window.scrollY > 200) {
      setShowScroll(true);
    } else if (showScroll && window.scrollY <= 200) {
      setShowScroll(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScrollTop, true);
    return function cleanUp(){
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScrollTop, true);
    }
  }, [])

  // window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollTop);

  return (
    <div>
    
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute exact path="/" component={TempLogin} />
        <PublicRoute
          exact
          path="/auth/:token"
          component={RoundLoadingWhileAuthenticating}
        />

        <MainContainer>
          <Switch>
            {privateRoutes.map((c, i) => (
              <PrivateRoutes key={i} exact path={c.src} component={c.comp} />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </MainContainer>
      </Switch>

      <div
        style={{
          display: showScroll ? "" : "none",
          position: "fixed",
          right: 20,
          bottom: 20,
        }}
      >
        <Fab
          onClick={() =>
            window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" })
          }
          color="primary"
          aria-label="add"
        >
          <ExpandLessIcon />
        </Fab>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried running this on two pages on one page it works fine and on other it does not work. Any help would be great.

Comment: The code you show works, show us the the one that does not

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()   // Create a ref object
```

}

```
  componentDidMount() {
  this.myRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

}

```
 render() {
   return <div ref={this.myRef}></div>
```

}   // attach the ref property to a Dom element